# Ag-grid custom tool tip component doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

My custom tooltip is pretty simple

custom.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ITooltipAngularComp} from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-columnheader-tooltip-component',
  templateUrl: './custom-columnheader-tooltip-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-columnheader-tooltip-component.css']
})

export class CustomColumnheaderTooltipComponent implements ITooltipAngularComp {
  private params: any;

  agInit(params): void {
    console.log("test tooltip");
    this.params = params;
  }
}
```

custom.html file:

{{params.value}}

I imported the component in app.module.ts file and added it as part of declarations and withComponents

app.module.ts file:

```
    import {CustomColumnheaderTooltipComponent} from '...';

    declarations: [
    CustomColumnheaderTooltipComponent],
    imports: [AgGridModule.withComponents([CustomColumnheaderTooltipComponent])]

my main component which calls this custom tooltip is as follows:

main.ts
    frameworkComponents = {
        customTooltip: CustomColumnheaderTooltipComponent}

    IN my default col Definitions:
      defaultColDef: ColDef = {
        enableRowGroup: true,
        filter: true,
        resizable: true,
        sortable: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        valueFormatter: this.cellValueFormatter.bind(this), // numeric formatting
        cellRenderer: this.cellRenderer,
        headerTooltip: 'hi',
        tooltipComponent:'customTooltip'
      };
```

I was hoping the header tooltip string will be picked up by the tool tip component and it is displayed as a part of that component as 'header name: hi' but my application just displays 'hi' as the tool tip. I cant see the console logging within the agInit() , basically it doesn't connect to that component for the tool tip. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have problem in registering your custom tooltip

In my app.module.ts

I would do something like below -

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents(
        [CustomColumnheaderTooltipComponent]
    )
],
declarations: [
    ............,
    CustomColumnheaderTooltipComponent,
    ...........
],
```

Check this [github example](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-angular-cli-example/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts) from official ag grid doc

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am already using it the same way. I missed to mention imports[] in my questions.